# Unable to add onPress on react-native-elements's seachbar in searchIcon props

Tags: javascript, react-native, searchbar, react-native-elements

```
<SearchBar
          containerStyle= {{backgroundColor: '#fff',borderWidth: 1}}
          inputContainerStyle= {{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
          searchIcon={{ size: 24,name: this.state.searchIconName }}
          onChangeText={text => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
          onClear={text => this.SearchFilterFunction('')}
          placeholder="Type Here..."
          value={this.state.search}
          />
          <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
          )}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
```

I want to replace searchIcon on change.

in **searchIcon={{ size: 24 }}**
[enter image description he[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg9X1.png)re](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6hFs.png)

Comment: What are you passing in this.state.searchIconName ?

Comment: I am rendering icon dynamically like it will be a search icon at start and become back icon when user start typing